# How can the Simpsons afford such a nice house?

Tags: the-simpsons

*The Simpsons* survie on only Homers salary which can't be that great. Still, they own two cars and live in a two-story four bedroom detached house in an average size American city. How could they afford this?

Comment: Inherited house ? maybe?

Comment: This was made fun of several times on the show, probably most memorably in *Homer's Enemy*.

Comment: Grimey was exaggerating.

Comment: The same way many americans live - with a ridiculous mortgage and crippling debt they'll never be able to pay off.

Comment: *"Inherited house ? maybe?"*  I'm pretty sure Homer tells a story about him and Marge getting married, in which Abe offers to give them his house.  In return, Homer says Abe will always be welcome.  Bart asks WTE *"How long did it take you to ship him off to the retirement home?"* to which Homer replies *"Couple of weeks"* then they all laugh..  In contrast to that, in the episode where Homer takes up a job at a rival power plant run by an evil genius, Homer and Marge realize they *owe* more on the house than it is worth, and just walk out.  So ..take your pick, really.

Comment: @AnkitSharma  Oops!  Forgot to notify you of my response to your comment.  In any case, I had the details wrong.  More info. [here](http://simpsons.wikia.com/wiki/742_Evergreen_Terrace) on the Simpson's Wiki.

Comment: You're familiar with the subprime crisis, I take it?

Comment: Maybe its Springfield: suburb of Detroit. They do have the tire fire, after all.

Answer (score 15):

Aside from the obvious answer: It's a cartoon--we can make some assumptions with real-world data.

The average Nuclear Power Plant Operator's salary is [72.5k a year](http://www.payscale.com/research/US/Job=Nuclear_Power_Reactor_Operator/Salary). The average house price in Springfield, oh...let's say Missouri is [107k](http://www.zillow.com/springfield-mo/home-values/). Let's say that this is a really nice house for the area and they paid $150k. Let's figure they got in on an OK interest rate which would put them somewhere in the range of $1300/month for their mortgage payment? Given that their cars are obviously well used, Marge does most of the cooking (not a lot of eating out expenses), neither kid goes to private school, and they all seem to have a very tiny wardrobe, I'm thinking they're getting by fairly OK paycheck-to-paycheck.

And living paycheck-to-paycheck is the modern american dream. :)

Comment: *"Given that their cars are obviously well used, Marge does most of the cooking (not a lot of eating out expenses), neither kid goes to private school, and they all seem to have a very tiny wardrobe, I'm thinking they're getting by fairly OK paycheck-to-paycheck."*  ..where is "Homer's beer budget" in those figures?  ;)

Comment: @AndrewThompson I'm guessing Duff isn't top shelf stuff. :)

Comment: Also, keep in mind they've remortgaged several times. In the episode *The Computer Wore Menace Shoes*, when Homer has to run the deed to his house to purchase a computer, the system comes back indicating they're on their 5th mortgage.

Comment: Either houses in Springfield, Missouri are dirt-cheap, or houses in Britain are bloody expensive.

Comment: Let's not forget that the whole show seems to be stuck in a groundhog year where nobody ages and nothing changes. It's possible they skirt by on nothing and never run out because they happen to loop before the crushing debt forces Homer to suicide, Marge to prostitution, Bart to prison, and Lisa to raise Maggie by herself by taking on a sugar daddy.

Answer (score 11):

> In order for the Simpson family to purchase the home, Abraham Simpson sold his old house and wrote Homer a check for $15,000, allowing him to pay the down payment on the house. In No Loan Again, Naturally it is revealed that the Simpsons are unable to afford their mortgage anymore, due to Homer constantly loaning money against the house, which causes Ned Flanders to buy the house for $101,000 and rent it to the Simpsons.

Source: http://simpsons.wikia.com/wiki/742_Evergreen_Terrace